# System.Reflection.Emit::DynamicMethod: Is there a tool to have IL code generated from existing assembly?

Tags: .net, reflection.emit, il, dynamicmethod

I want to create a dynamic method with code that's a bit more than trivial.

So I want to create a hard coded version of the method body and have a compiled version of it examined by some tool that's returning OpCos and parameters to me so I can insert them using `ILGenerator::Emit()`.

Is there such tool available? (Maybe that's a stupid question. I couldn't find it using Google, though.)

Comment: Dont use `DyanmicMethod` then. Go the normal route via `MethodBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But it looks like using MethodBuilder instead of DynamicMethod doesn't help me from creating IL code.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by that.

Comment: The question title is: "Is there a tool to have IL code generated from existing assembly?" That's got nothing to do with which method I'm using to create a dynamic function body.

Comment: Who downvoted my question? By what reasons?

Comment: Asking for downvotes gives you more downvotes and asking for a tool is frowned upon: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question/254394#254394

Comment: I see. I assume that's because it's not wanted to endorse the one over the other. However, the term "tool" doesn't necessarily target commercial products or similar. A "tool" could be some SDK tool. Wouldn't this tend to be considered a valid question? With tons of different SDK tools and GitHub projects it's impossible to find a way through. Someone facing the same problem I have could benefit from an answer, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, so I can give you only a vague answer: try [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/). It allows you to inspect IL in an existing assembly and modify it, which sounds close to what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you. I've found a section in the HowTo section that seems to do the trick. I'll try that. THANKS!